# Сказуемое?

Tags: сказуемое

В предложении: "Вот и **готова** квартира", квартира- подлежащее, готова- сказуемое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правы, хотя к сказуемому можно отнести также частицу "вот и"

Comment: Относительно школьной программы 3 класса, правильно будет подчеркнуть "вот и готова", как сказуемое? Я правильно поняла?

Comment: Для третьего класса, конечно, достаточно выделить сказуемое "готова".

Comment: Для 11 тоже. Частицы не являются членами предложения.